# Cube Sync issue in SSAS

Tags: synchronization, ssas, cube

Can I sync cube between two servers (`Server B` and `Server C`) by running the XMLA query on `Server A`?.... Currently I am getting an error :( . Please find below XMLA script and error output

**XMLA Query**:

```
<Synchronize xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
<Source>
<ConnectionString>Provider=MSOLAP.5;Data Source='+@ServerName+';Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog='+@DatabaseID+'</ConnectionString>
<Object>
    <DatabaseID>'+@DatabaseID+'</DatabaseID>
</Object>
</Source>
<SynchronizeSecurity>CopyAll</SynchronizeSecurity>
<ApplyCompression>true</ApplyCompression>
</Synchronize>
```

**Error Message**:

```
OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "Server A" returned message "Errors in the OLE DB provider. The data source or location is not valid. Provide a valid server to which to connect.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. I got the issue.

We can run our XMLA script on Server B from Server A by using remote query execution.

Put whole XMLA script into variable **@XMLA** and **@LinkedSyncServerName = Server B**
Before running this query **test your linked server connections**

```
EXEC (''' + @XMLA + N''') AT [' + @LinkedSyncServerName + N']'
```